# navbar default overlap with content

Tags: html, css

hello in my project i have a navbar navbar-default class, this menu is overlapping whit my content  when i want to scroll my website.

this is my [image: screenshot]

i found a script that fixed this menu to the top but still overlapping with my content, this is the script

```
 window.onscroll = changePos;

    function changePos() {
        var header = document.getElementById("uno");
        if (window.pageYOffset > 70) {
            header.style.position = "fixed";
            header.style.top = "0";
        } else {
            header.style.position = "";
            header.style.top = "";
        }
    }
```

also i have my css code and html code of the navbar menu, this it the code

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a{
    color:black;
}

 .navbar-default{
     margin: auto;
     background: rgb(178,205,73);
     }


.nav.navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;

}

.nav.navbar-nav li,.nav.navbar-nav li  a
{
    display:inline;
    float:none;
    line-height:40px;
}

.right.carousel-control, .left.carousel-control{

 background:linear-gradient( rgba(146,211,236,1.00) 15%, rgb(0,171,235) 150%   );

}


.item.active ,.carousel-inner{
    background-color: rgba(146,211,236,1.00) ;
}
```

this is my menu

```
 <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12" id="uno">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                                 <div class="navbar-header">
                                             <button type="button" 
                                              class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                                               data-toggle="collapse" data-
                                       target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" 
                                          aria-controls="navbar">
                                                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle 
                                                 navigation</span>
                                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                              </button>
                                          </div>
                                           <div id="navbar" class="navbar-
                                              collapse collapse">
                                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                                <li><a href="#">Conozcanos</a>
                                                </li>
                                                 <li><a href="#">Derechos y 
                                                  Deberes Del Usuario</a>
                                                 </li>
                                                  <li><a 
                                                  href="#">Responsabilidad 
                                                  Social</a>
                                                  </li>
                                                  <li><a href="#">Correo 
                                                   Corporativo</a>
                                                  </li>
                                                  </ul>
                                                </div>
                                           </nav>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
```

Comment: the navbar  appears to overlap behind the container. i don't understand how..

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below code to your CSS file:

```
.navbar{
    z-index: 9999; /* You can add any positive number here */
}
```

z-index property will make your element stay on top of other elements.

Comment: i used the class navbar-fixed-top, but i want the navbar in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your menu at the top, I suggest you use stickyjs. That should probably eliminate any other problem you have. A screenshot would also help to know what exactly you issue is